# How to update "my_field" of N posts in less than N queries?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, update-attributes

How could I improve the performance of the following updates ?

```
Post.find(id1).update_attributes(:my_field => value1)
Post.find(id2).update_attributes(:my_field => value2)
Post.find(id3).update_attributes(:my_field => value3)
        ...                               ...
Post.find(idN).update_attributes(:my_field => valueN)
```

Comment: There isn't a way around finding and updating a record as you will still need to execute a SELECT and a UPDATE statement on your database.  Perhaps you could take id[x] though and put it in a loop so you don't repeat a lot of code?

Comment: Well, I wonder if there is some sophisticated SQL query to speed this up...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a single SQL query using [update_all](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all)

```
Post.update_all("field = 'value'", "id IN (id1, id2...)")
```

EDIT: This won't work with a single statement, of course you will have N `Post.update_all` sentences for N posts since each post will have different value, but since it makes and SQL UPDATE and doens't instantiate the Post objects is currently faster than `Post.find.update_attributes`.

Comment: what will make 'value' increase for each id ?

Comment: I have different N new values.